# In Python, I'm attempting to make a fast way of replacing bogus parentheses in a string with periods

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a string with only '(', ')', and '.' and I want to replace all the () that don't match with corresponding () with a .

For example:

```
s1 = '((.))'
s2 = '((.)'
s3 = '(.))'
```

Fixing these would give:

```
rs1 = '((.))'
rs2 = '.(.)'
rs3 = '(.).'
```

Right now, I'm using a stack to get all the bogus () then using a list comprehension to replace them.

Given that fold is one of the s* strings above, here's my code:

```
hashFoldStack = []
makePeriods = set()
for hashFoldIndex, hashFoldCharacter in enumerate(fold):
    if hashFoldCharacter == '(':
        hashFoldStack.append(hashFoldIndex)
    elif hashFoldCharacter == ')':
        if len(hashFoldStack) > 0:
            hashFoldStack.pop()
        else:
            makePeriods.update([hashFoldIndex])
if len(hashFoldStack) > 0:
    for leftover in hashFoldStack:
        makePeriods.update(leftover)

hashFold = ''.join(['.' if hashIndex in makePeriods\
                        else hashCharacter\
                        for hashIndex, hashCharacter\
                        in enumerate(fold)])
```

Question 1: For the first part where I'm creating the makePeriods stack, is there a faster way to do this?
Question 2: Is a list comprehension going to be faster than a lambda or some function from the re module?

Comment: You might want to post working code on codereview.stackexchange.com.  If you want speed improvements, then (1) use a profiler and (2) use `timeit` to see which alternative is **actually** faster.  It's better to actually measure the two choices than ask hypothetical questions.

Comment: I've seen many side by sides of lambdas vs comprehensions. They are there to aid the programmer,  not the machine. Think of lambda as a tool for recursive solutions (functional), and comprehensions for iterative approaches (procedural).

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is pretty fast. Let's make it work now :-)

```
if len(hashFoldStack) > 0:
    for leftover in hashFoldStack:
        makePeriods.update(leftover)
```

should be just:

```
makePeriods.update(hashFoldStack)
```

I was searching net a bit and [here](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/) I found a great article about the topic. It mentions that the string construction by join and list comprehension is one of the fastest ways. If you want to optimize further, use some way of profiling as the comments suggest. You can wrap the code in for loop that runs lots of times and then launch the script like this `$ python -m cProfile script.py`.

By the way, there could be a way to make it faster by constructing `hashFoldList` in the loop together with `hashFoldStack`. At the end, it would be just: `hashFold = ''.join(hashFoldList)`. Anyway, an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it only need to work on segments of two parentheses at most? Here's a simple answer:

```
def pblocks(pblocks):
    whole = []
    for i in pblocks:
        L, R = i.split('.')
        p = '.'
        if len(L) == len(R):
            part = [L, R] 
        elif len(L) < len(R):
            part = [L, ').']
        else:
            part = ['.(', R]
        whole.append(part)
    return ['.'.join(i) for i in whole]
```

For more elaborate examples, you'd have to give me a moment, but I think you could continue deleting segments until `len(L) == len(R)`, but I'm not sure what you'd want done with multiple leftover parens.